# HTML tags are not reflected in Gxt Grid

Tags: java, html, gwt, gxt

I have a GXT grid where I am applying html  tag to highlight the text "def" in the word "defining". But instead of taking as HTML tag, it considers the  as a string and displays output as `<mark>def</mark>ining`. Can you please help me how to resolve this ?

```
private static String doHighlight(String dtoData){ //dtoData is "defining"
    int dtoLength = dtoData.length();
    int i = -1;
    String newDtoData = null;
    String finalDtoData = null;
    String highlightStartTag = "<mark>";
    String highlightEndTag = "</mark>";

    if (dtoData != null && dtoData != "") {
        i = dtoData.toLowerCase().indexOf("def", i+1);
        if(i<0){
            finalDtoData = dtoData;
        }else{
            newDtoData = highlightStartTag +dtoData.substring(0, i) + dtoData.substring(i, "def".length()) + highlightEndTag;
            finalDtoData = newDtoData + dtoData.substring("def".length(), dtoLength);
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    return finalDtoData;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you use this `doHighlight` method to draw in the GXT Grid? If it is part of the value provider, or in the cell, etc, so that I can show where to change more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Map<Integer, String> findMatches(String searchText, String dtoValue, int rowCount) {    
Map<Integer,String> matchesMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
if (dtoValue != null && dtoValue != "") {
        i = dtoValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText, i+1);
        if(i>=0){
            newDtoData = dtoValue.replaceAll(searchText, "<span style='background-color: yellow; !important'>"+searchText+"</span>");
            matchesMap.put(rowCount, newDtoData);
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    return matchesMap;
```

Pass the above matchesMap to the below loop and iterate it over the rowcount. You can get the cell using column and row count. After getting the cell element, you can set the innerHTML.

```
for(int rowId:matchesMap.keySet()){
        if(!matchesMap.get(rowId).isEmpty()){
            Element cellElement = viewComponent.getView().getCell(rowId, columnId); 
            if(cellElement != null){
                cellElement.setInnerHTML(matchesMap.get(rowId));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the requirement has something to do with the layout, I personally would use a cell for that column of the grid.

Something like this should work:

```
myColumn.setCell(new AbstractCell<String>() {
      @Override
      public void render(Context context,
                         String value,
                         SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null && value != "") {
          int i = value.toLowerCase().indexOf("def");
          if (i < 0) {
            sb.append(value);
          } else {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<mark>")
              .append(value.substring(0, i))
              .append(value.substring(i, "def".length()))
              .appendHtmlConstant("</mark>")
              .append(value.substring("def".length(), value.length()));
         }
       }
     }
   });
```

Surely, that's not complete, but it should give you an idea how to solve it.

Hope that helps.